# WPF - Metro Dialog Settings (mahapps) on the top of the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a WPF application, and I use a `metro dialog` to show messages. Can I show the message on the top of the window? Can I modify the location of the `popup`?

Comment: Are you using any UI framework like MahApps to get the "Metro" theme?  Dialogs are usually pretty straightforward to use.

Comment: Yes, I use the MahApps Metro for the "Metro" theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

```
try
{
     var mySettings = new MetroDialogSettings
     {
         AffirmativeButtonText = "Yes"
     };

     var cd = new CustomDialog
     {
         VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
         VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
     };

     await DialogManager.ShowMetroDialogAsync(this, cd, mySettings);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```